# Loading tables into Sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to know how to insert by default (when you load the app for the first time you find this data) data into my sqlite db, by example

**gameidno**:1    **gamedate**:30/11/2014  **gameteam**:Spurs
**gameopponent**: LAL

**gameidno**:2
**gamedate**:05/12/2014
**gameteam**:Spurs
**gameopponent**: Mavs

**gameidno**:3
**gamedate**:09/12/2014
**gameteam**:Spurs
**gameopponent**: Memphis

Here is my DBhelper:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists gamestable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "gameidno"
            + " INTEGER,"
            + "gamedate"
            + " TEXT,"
            + "gameteam"
            + " TEXT,"
            + "gameopponent" + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + gamestable);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addGame(GameModel gameitem) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


    contentValues.put("gameidno", gameitem.gameidno);
    contentValues.put("gamedate", gameitem.gamedate );
    contentValues.put("gameteam", gameitem.gameteam);
    contentValues.put("gameopponent", gameitem.gameopponent);
    db.insert("gamestable", null, contentValues);

    db.close();
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class AddGames extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_addrecord;
    private EditText txtpname;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    GameModel pm;
    private Spinner gamesSpinner;
    private Spinner timeSpinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder);

        txtpname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        gamesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.games_spinner);  
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.reminders_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gamesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        timeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.time_spinner);    
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.time_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        timeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1); 


        btn_addrecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_addrecord.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         DatabaseHelper db;
         ProductModel pm;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            if (txtpname.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || gamesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(AddGames.this, "Please add values..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.getWritableDatabase();
                pm = new GamesModel();
                pm.idno = (txtpname.getText().toString());
                pm.gamename = gameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pm.reminderway = timeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.i("gameidno,gamename,productprice", "" + pm.idno + ""
                        + pm.gamename + "" + pm.reminderway);
                   db.addGame(pm);
                Toast.makeText(Addgame.this, "Record Added successfully.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish(); 
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

GameModel Class:

```
public class GameModel {
 public String gameidno="", gamedate="", gameteam="", gameopponent="";

    public String getgamedate() {
        return gamedate;
    }

    public void setgamedate(String gamedate) {
        this.gamedate = gamedate;
    }

    public String getgameteam() {
        return gameteam;
    }

    public void setgameteam(String gameteam) {
        this.gameteam = gameteam;
    }


    public String getgameopponent() {
        return gameopponent;
    }

    public void setgameopponent(String gameopponent) {
        this.gameopponent = gameopponent;
    }


    public String getgameIdno() {
        return gameidno;
    }

    public void setgameIdno(String idno) {
        this.gameidno = gameidno;
    }


}
```

Comment: By default data ? i dint get you

Comment: Hey, when you load the app for the first time you find this data

Comment: at least read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)

Comment: @MounirElfassi you need to add constructor of your GameModel  class .tell me if you need code related to it.

Comment: Please Guinaz Show me how

Comment: @selvin i didn't know what to do, even after reading the documentation

Comment: @gulnaz-ghanchi plz show me how

Comment: okay, tell me, do u have ur GameModel class right ? what u have written in that class ? you have to help me too with your code, so that i can give you exact solution,

Comment: @gulnaz-ghanchi i have updated my post with GameModel class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this constructor in your `GameModel` Class.

```
 public GameModel (String gameidno,String gamedate,String gameteam,String gameopponent){
    this.gameidno= gameidno;
    this.gamedate= gamedate;
    this.gameteam= gameteam;
    this.gameopponent= gameopponent;
}
```

And in your activity from where you want to add values just use following code.

```
db.addGame(new GameModel(yourvalue, yourvalue,yourvalue,yourvalue));
```

I am sure it will add in your `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a preference variable inside your oncreate method like bellow:

```
public class AddGames extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SharedPreferences pref;

private Button btn_addrecord;
private EditText txtpname;
DatabaseHelper db;
GameModel pm;
private Spinner gamesSpinner;
private Spinner timeSpinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder);

    pref=getSharedPreferences("your_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean firstTime=pref.getBoolean("first_launch", false);
    if(firstTime == false){

            pm = new GamesModel();
            pm.idno = "your_id";
            pm.gamename = "your_game_name";
            pm.reminderway = "your_reminder";

            pm.addGame(pm);

            Toast.makeText(Addgame.this, "Fisrt Record Added successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       SharedPreference.Editor ed=pref.edit();
       pref.putBoolean("first_launch", true);
       ed.commit();
    }
  }
```